# Java socket sends some data during connection to server 2

Tags: java, sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java socket sends some data during connection to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219559/java-socket-sends-some-data-during-connection-to-server)

I have two very very simple java programs - client and server.They establish connection through sockets.
Server reads characters from stream and prints them to console.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class DataServerSIMS {
    static final int LISTENING_PORT = 2002;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket listener;  //Checks the connection requests
        Socket connection;      //To interact with other progs
        Reader incoming;            //Stream
        try {
            listener = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
            TextIO.putln("Listening on port "+LISTENING_PORT);
            while (true) {
                connection = listener.accept();
                try {
                    incoming = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                    while (true) {
                        int ch = incoming.read();
                        if (ch == 1 || ch == '\r')
                            break;
                            System.out.print((char)ch);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    incoming.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    TextIO.putln("Error: "+e);
                }//end try recieving data
            }//end while
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            TextIO.putln("Sorry, the server has shut down.");
            TextIO.putln("Error: "+e);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Client only establishes socket-connection.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class TempClientSIMS {
    //static final int LISTENING_PORT = 32007;
    static final int LISTENING_PORT = 2002;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket listener;  //Checsk the connection requests
        Socket connection;      //To interact with other progs
        Socket connectionToServer = null;   //Socket
        Reader incoming;            //Stream
        try {

            TextIO.putln("Localhost connects to:"+LISTENING_PORT);

            connectionToServer = new Socket ("localhost", 2002);

            TextIO.putln("Connected ");

            long i=0;
            while (i<2000000000) {
                i++;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            TextIO.putln("Sorry, the server has shut down.");
            TextIO.putln("Error: "+e);
            return;
        }
    }


}
```

**Client doesn't send any data to server.**

I launched both programs on my PC.
Client printed:

```
Localhost connects to:2002
Connected
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Server printed:

```
Listening on port 2002
FdsfsdfsError: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

It is clear why this string "`Error: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`" is printed on server's console.
But I haven't any idea what does it mean: "`Fdsfsdfs`"?
And can I prevent the printing of this string "`Fdsfsdfs`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check for End of Stream using Reader. Add that check to your code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29

```
                 //Try this 
                 while (true) {
                    int ch = incoming.read();
                    if (ch == 1 || ch == '\r'||ch == -1)
                        break;
                        System.out.print((char)ch);
                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking for EOS when you read from the stream on the server. You should break the while loop if the result of the read is equal to -1.

Something like this:

```
while (true) {
    int ch = incoming.read();
    if (ch == -1)
        break;

    }

    ...
```

Also use Thread.sleep() to pause execution.

Answer (score 1):

ch will be < 0 when the socket is closed.  your code does not handle that.

Comment: Ok! Thank you! It is also interesting for me: Should I close the sockets after the performing of I/O  operations in case if I want to perform another I/O operation later?

Comment: @Vladimir You must close it if you get < 0, or any IOException other than SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: And what about if I want to perform two consequtive writes:                                                 OutputStream outToServerStream;
                    outToServerStream = connectionToServer.getOutputStream();
                    outToServerStream.write(OutputArray);
outToServerStream.flush();                                                                                                                       Is it normal practice? Or it's better to close socket connection after the first writing operation and make new connection for next write operation?